# Running js file in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run this simple file in an empty folder

```
// time.js
const moment = require('moment')

function getDay() {
  var today = moment().day()
  console.log(today);
}

getDay()
```

using `node time.js`

But I get

```
Error: Cannot find module 'moment'
```

However I have run `npm install -g moment` and `npm install moment`.

What noob error am I doing?

Comment: If the folder is empty, then you forgot to add an package json and install moment inside this folder. So require can't find anything. Or is there a folder named `node_modules` present?

Comment: @cyrix so you can't just run a standalone .js file in the terminal ?

Comment: sure you can, but don't rely on npm packages if you didn't install them inside your project folder

Comment: i added an example on how to quickly set up npm for a project folder. (note: it's an minimal example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the following commands on your console inside your folder:

```
npm init // just hit enter some times or follow the process
npm install moment --save
node time.js
```

Note: You could skip the npm init part but I wouldn't recommend it due to dependency control.

Comment: So how would you run it without npm ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You got nodejs installed therefore let npm handle your dependencies ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure you have initiated the package before requiring dependencies,

to install moment

```
npm install moment
```

to initialize the package

```
npm init
```

This will create the package.json, make sure that "moment^x.x.x" is available within the dependencies

Set your time.js as the main.js in package's scripts as well,

for example

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node time.js",
  },
```

and then to run the app

```
npm start
```